# Way to count the data transferred in WCF

Tags: wcf

Is there a way how to count the data transferred through a service in WCF?

Comment: What do you mean by "count the data"? What type (binding) of service are you using?

Comment: WCF supports a large number of [performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735098.aspx) which you can monitor using PerfMon. Those typically involve things like number of calls made (total or per second) and so on

Comment: I'm using NetTcpBinding in a self-hosted application but it doesn't matter, I'm just curious if there is a way to monitor the amount of data sent (ie. count the number of bytes transferred from the service to client during a session within the wcf operation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of performance counters created for the WCF applications and hosts. IIS (if used as a host) also have several.

You should be able to find one or more that match your expectations. If not, then you can create your own performance counter in your service(s).